# How to query on a column of datatype long storing datetime values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a table which has a column called ccDate of type long which stores the date values in long format  - for example 20021218. Actually it is a datetime value for 2002-12-18 (yyyy-MM-DD). Now i want to query records from this table comparing this datetime values. for example get all records where ccDate < todays's date. How can i do this ? (note : i am working on SQLServer). I am looking for a database function which can automatically convert these long values to date & compare while querying.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that your actual datatype in SQL Server is an `integer` then something like this will work:

```
select *
From myTable
Where Cast(Cast(ccDate as varchar(10)) as datetime) < getdate()
```